# Fredholm Integral help finding eigenvector

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I believe I'm dealing here with some Fredhold integral operators. For the continuous function $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$, let the function $Kf$ be defined by

$$(Kf)(x)=\int_0^1(1+xt)f(t)dt$$

I want to find all the nonzero eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors for the operator K. I find it to be a somewhat tiresome task. Here's what I have,

$$(Kf)(x)=\int_0^1(1+xt)f(t)dt=\int_0^1f(t)dt+x\int_0^1tf(t)dt$$

Letting $$a=\int_0^1f(t)dt$$ and $$b=\int_0^1tf(t)dt$$
We have $$(Kf)(x)=a+bx$$

Using the eigenvalue equation $Kf=\mu f$, I can solve for $f$ and obtain $$\frac{a+bx}{\mu}=f(x)$$ 
So $$a=\int_0^1 f(t)dt=\int_0^1\frac{a+bt}{\mu}dt=\frac{a}{\mu}\int_0^1dt+\frac{b}{\mu}\int_0^1tdt=\frac{a}{\mu}+\frac{b}{2\mu}$$ Thus $$a(1-\frac{1}{\mu})-b(\frac{1}{2\mu})=0$$ Similarly, $$b=\int_0^1tf(t)=\int_0^1t(\frac{a+bt}{\mu})dt=\frac{a}{\mu}\int_0^1tdt+\frac{b}{\mu}\int_0^1t^2dt=\frac{a}{2\mu}+\frac{b}{3\mu}$$

$$\implies a(\frac{-1}{2\mu})+b(1-\frac{1}{3\mu})=0$$ Therefore,

$$\begin{cases}
a(1-\frac{1}{\mu})-b(\frac{1}{2\mu})=0   \\
a(\frac{-1}{2\mu})+b(1-\frac{1}{3\mu})=0   \\
\end{cases}$$

So here's where I'm stuck. After some elbow grease, I ended up getting $\mu=0,\frac{2}{3}\pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}$ when $b=0$. I'm not sure if I'm correct and I don't know how to verify if I'm correct either since I don't know how to find the eigenvector. Any help will be kindly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation shows that any eigenfunction must be of the form
$$
f(x) = a+ bx,
$$
and if we denote by $\mu$ the corresponding eigenvalue, we must have
$$
\begin{split}
a+\frac b2&=\mu a,\\
\frac a2 + \frac b3 &= \mu b.
\end{split}
$$
We see that if $a=0$ then it forces $b=0$. Hence there is no nontrivial eigenfunction with $a=0$. Now by using the property that an eigenfunction stays an eigenfunction when multiplied by any number, we can assume $a=1$. This leads to the quadratic equation
$$
b^2 + \frac43b-1=0,
$$
whose solutions are
$$
b_{1,2} = \frac{-2\pm\sqrt{13}}3.
$$
The corresponding eigenvalues are
$$
\mu_{1,2} = 1+\frac b2 = \frac{4\pm\sqrt{13}}6.
$$
To conclude, up to scaling, the only nontrivial eigenfunctions of $K$ are
$$
f_{1,2}(x) = 3 + (-2\pm\sqrt{13}\,)\,x,
$$
which satisfy 
$$
Kf_n = \mu_nf_n,\qquad n=1,2.
$$

Comment: how did you get 3 +(-2 +- sqrt13)?

Comment: @User69127: I just multiplied $1+bx$ by $3$.